# UIviewcontroller - what time is the view property instantiated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i'm wondering about what time is exactely created the .view property of a UIViewController.

I created a ViewController, and in the init(coder: aDecoder) i started to set up few variables. when i tried to set up the viewController.view.backgroundColor it crashed.
I placed the same line of code inside the viewDidLoad and it worked.

this is my code

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("didload")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        println("init Coder")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.tabBarItem.title = nil
        //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() // CAUSE CRASH
    }
}
```

this is the error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Mari/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9CC10D9-409E-4604-A6F7-B3729E0B3D52/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F5DFDFE6-87B9-40AF-A26B-7B5A1506D203/test.app> (loaded)' with name '9pv-A4-QxB-view-tsR-hK-woN''
```

during the init coder the VC is instantiated, the tab bar can be set up cause it's from the root view controller ( a tab bar controller ), but the view is a property of the VC so during the init, is still not ready to be set up. am i right?

so... When is the view property exactely instantiated? 
when is the best moment to set it up ?

Comment: viewDidLoad, as its name suggests, is called right after the view is loaded into memory, so that is the best place to do additional setup of your views.

Answer (score 1):

The view is instantiated between the *initializer* (in your case `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`) and `viewDidLoad`.

Within that period, iOS loads the UI components from your IB files. As a developer you then have the possibility to customize the view (e.g. by changing colors) in `viewDidLoad`.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) about the **view controller lifecycle**.